# VBScript SQLite Connection String

Tags: sqlite, vbscript, hta

Is it possible to connect to a SQLite database using VBScript without using an ODBC driver? Perhaps by using the sqlite3.dll file? In the environment I'm working in, I'm unable to install the odbc driver that would enable connection via normal means. I apologize in advance if my question is not phrased correctly.

I'm trying to create an .hta file that can connect to a local sqlite database. Would normally use MS Access for this, but unfortunately due to licensing issues I am unable to do so in this scenario.

Comment: It is not very updated, but [this](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/litex) is what i use for similar cases, and works without problems when registering (is a activex wrapper) at user level in restricted scenarios.

Comment: This looks promising! could I beg a code example of you in vbscript for connecting to a sqlite .db file?

Comment: `Set oDB = CreateObject("LiteX.LiteConnection")` : `oDB.Open fileName` But the [repository](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/litex/documents) includes the full source code and a `.pdf` with a complete reference of the available interfaces and how to use them.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't install a driver (whether ODBC, OLEDB, or .NET), you'll have to use the sqlite command line program via .Exec/.Run and some kind of inter-process communication, or write a wrapper for the DLL in a suitable language (C, C++, C#, VB, ...).

You **can** use a .MDB via ADO even if Access is not installed (at least until Win 7).

Answer (score 2):

**3rd Party ODBC Driver:**

http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/html/index.html

**Connection string and including some sample code:**

```
Dim oCS     : oCS       = "Driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=@FSPEC@;StepAPI=;Timeout="
Dim oCNCT   : Set oCNCT = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )

oCS = Replace( oCS, "@FSPEC@", sCurDir + sFina )
oCNCT.Open oCS
WScript.Echo "connected to", sFina
```

**Reference:**

http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Help-with-SQLite-database-and-VBScript-m36358.aspx